# Why does partial fraction decomposition fail for higher-degree numerators?

Tags: power-series, partial-fractions

I can decompose

$${1\over(x-a)(x-b)} = {1\over(a-b)}({1\over(x-a)}-{1\over(x-b)}) = {1\over(a-b)}({x-b-x+a\over(x-a)(x-b)}) = {a-b \over (a-b)(x-a)(x-b)}$$

and

$${x\over(x-a)(x-b)} = {1\over(a-b)}({a\over(x-a)}-{b\over(x-b)})$$

however fail to decompose $$x^2\over (x-a)(x-b)$$ because standard procedure (substituting $x\to a$ and $x\to b$) produces

$${1\over(a-b)} ({a^2\over x-a} - {b^2\over x-b}) = {1\over(a-b)} ({a^2x - ba^2 - xb^2 + ab^2 \over (x-a)(x-b)}) = {1\over(a-b)} ({x(a^2 - b^2) - ab(a-b) \over (x-a)(x-b)}) =  {x(a+b) - ab \over (x-a)(x-b)}$$

This surprisingly implies that $x^2 = x(a+b)-ab$.

I realized that failure is caused by degree of nominator reaching the degree of denominator. I think that this is not an issue particularly for me since I can factor out the $x^n$ as long as I am finding generating function power series coefficients and x just stands for `shift`. But I am still curious to know

1. why <strike>dont tutorials discuss the root of the failure</strike>
   (though you can answer this also)
2. is the failure at higher degrees?
3. Is it related to [why are there more poles than zeroes](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10204)?
4. What is the point of $x^2 = x(a+b)-ab$?

Comment: Just pull out a constant to make it strictly proper will you?....

Comment: If the degree of the numerator-polynomial is equal or higher than the degree of the denominator-polynomial, you have to apply polynomial division first, then you can proceed with partial fraction.

Comment: The reason why it fails is because simple fractions all tend to zero when the variable tends to $\infty$, but a non-proper rational function tends to $\infty$ or a number $\neq0$ when the variable tends to $\infty$. The equality is not possible. That is why you do long division first, to extract the part that doesn't tend to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most simply put if you have
$$\frac A{x-a}+\frac B{x-b}$$
and add these together, you get
$${(A+B)x-aB-bA\over(x-a)(x-b)}.$$
So such a decomposition can only produce a numerator whose deg is at most 1.